# Example of simple inconsistent finite difference scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to make a presentation to illustrate the notions of consistency and stability. To do so, I'm doing some animations to illustrate the importance of each notion individually. However, I'm struggling to find a good example of a simple finite difference scheme on a PDE that is stable but inconsistent.

So I'm looking for a simple PDE which can be "approached" by an inconsistent finite difference scheme.

By simple I mean :

- Linear if possible
- The solution may be a function of one spatial variable.
- May be used for some other PDE, in order that this example does not seem too "made up"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the trivial and versatile scheme
$$u^{n+1}_j=u^n_j$$
whose stability seems granted, you might consider the Lax scheme for the 1D linear transport equation:
$$\partial_t u+a\partial_x u=0$$
for some constant $a$. It is a stabilisation of the unconditionally unstable centered scheme by replacing the $u_j^n$ term by the average of the two neighbouring values in space:
$$\frac{u_j^{n+1}-\frac12(u_{j+1}^{n}+u_{j-1}^n)}{\Delta t}+a\frac{u_{j+1}^{n}-u_{j-1}^n}{2\Delta x}=0$$
It is stable under CFL condition $\le 1$ and consistent only provided that $\Delta x^2/\Delta t\to 0$ while $(\Delta t,\Delta x) \to (0,0)$.  Thus this is an example of a scheme which really approaches a PDE but is not stricto sensu consistent. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know whether this scheme has a name? And de you think the inconsistency wil be visible if I solve the transport equation with it with Python for example?

Comment: This is the Lax Scheme. Yes is should be visible if you take $\Delta t$ small enough wrt $\Delta x$.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see you already put the name on your answer. Pretty well, this is the answer I was looking for!